# Differentiability paradox

Tags: derivatives, continuity

We know that if a function is differentiable in (a,b) then it is continuous in (a,b).
Consider the function f defined on -1 < x < 1, given by:
f(x)=x, when x>=0 and f(x)=x-1, when x<0.
Then f is differentiable in (-1,1), but not continuous in (-1,1). Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: What makes you think it's differentiable in $x=0$ ?

Comment: This is a matter of definition.  "differentiable" requires "continuous".  the function which is $0$ for $x≤0$ and $1$ for $x>0$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.  Period.

Comment: @lulu It's not a matter of definition. It's a matter of proving that every differentiable function is continuous.

Comment: @Adayah  Really, that depends on your definition of "differentiable".  I'd require that the function be continuous at the point and then require that the left and right derivatives at that point exist and coincide.  I can imagine a different definition which folds everything in.  What definition do you want?

Comment: @lulu The very standard definition is that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ exists for each $x_0$. Never seen anyone using any other definition.

Answer (score 1):

No, because $f$ is not differentiable at zero, its point of discontinuity. After all,

$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{h - 0}{h} = 1$$

while

$$\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \frac{h - 1 - 0}{h} = \infty.$$